# simple calculation of integer and decimal number in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to multiply 2 values. Quantity is integer and credit price is decimal number. When I run this code nothing happens.

Does anyone know what is the issue?

Thank you.

```
 $(function(){ // bind the recalc function to the quantity fields

    $("#oneCreditSum").after('<label></label>Total: Aud <span id=\"total\"></span><br><br>');

    $("#quantity").bind('keyup', recalc);

    function recalc(){
        var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
        var creditPrice = $('#creditPrice').val();
        var total = quantity * creditPrice;
        $("#total").text(total);
    }});
```

Comment: Is there any javascript error you're getting?

Comment: Can you add the html? #quantity - a textbox? so is #creditPrice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parseFloat on the values, and alert each one individually to test.

A few other (unrelated) improvements:

1. Use keyup() function:

   ```
   $("#quantity").keyup(recalc);
   ```
2. Make function anonymous:

   ```
   $("#quantity").keyup(function(){...});
   ```
3. Use $(this) on #quantity in the function to avoid calling the jQuery selector again

You could also consider condensing this into a single line of code:

```
    $("#total").text(parseFloat($('#quantity').val()) * parseFloat($('#creditPrice').val()));
```

To zero-pad you might try something toFixed():

```
var num = 10;
var result = num.toFixed(2); // result will equal 10.00
```

I got this snippet from the following site

http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, that was very helpful. 
one more subquestion: is there a way of limiting the decimal point to show  e.g. 10.20 ?

Comment: Edited my answer with this. Would you consider accepting this as your answer

Answer (score 5):

use

**[parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/ParseFloat)**

before calculation on both numbers which parses a string argument and returns a floating point number.

```
var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
var creditPrice = $('#creditPrice').val();
var total = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(creditPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in whole number only you can use this function instead:

[parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp)

Comment: agreed, that's i have posted link for further detail